# How do I bind 'jk' to Esc key in Vi-Mode in tcsh shell

Tags: vim, shell, tcsh

I love and use vim daily on tcsh. I love everything about vim. And one of the reasons why I love it so much is I dont have to lift my hands to do stuff. I have `jk` mapped to `Esc` key in vim. But unfortunately, I cant get the same thing on tcsh shell.

Can someone help me `bindkey` `jk` to `Esc` on tcsh ?

Also please guide me to tcsh and vi-mode articles/tutorials/guides/tip-n-tricks

Comment: You're talking about the sequence of two keys, j and k? Wouldn't be surprised if there's no way to do that with `bindkey`, since the docs all refer to singular "key" for binding. If you used `bash` though, readline does support key sequences. (And there are many many other reasons to switch to bash!) Personally I have capslock remapped to escape globally (with xmodmap) - that could be a good alternative.

Comment: Jefromi, yes I am talking about the sequence `jk`. That's what I'm used to as `Esc` on vim and unfortuantely/fortunately I should stick with tcsh for now. I'm sure `bash` has its answers, but I'm looking for a tcsh specific one. Thanks.

Comment: You might get more responses to this on superuser.  It doesn't appear to be programming specific.

Answer (score 2):

It might help if you showed the binding command that you use in vim.

However, this ***might*** do what you're looking for:

```
bindkey -v
bindkey "jj" self-insert-command
bindkey -s "jk" "^["
```

Note: for the last command, if you type it or paste it into the command line, you will have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>j</kbd> or press <kbd>j</kbd> twice to get the "j" character. To get "^[" you can just type those characters or you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

After you enter these three commands (or add them to your `~/.tcshrc` and start a new shell), pressing the keys <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> while in insert mode will insert the letter "j" on the command line. If you press <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> while in insert mode, it will switch to command mode (like pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks. Will try out and let you know. Appreciate the help.